# Unitise Scattered Mask Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, scipy, interpolation

I want to visualise interpolated scattered data by masking the envelope of the given geometry. Prior to the interpolation a matrix is computed where the points outside of the combustion chamber are NaN but also some points inside at which should be interpolated.
My approach was to compute a mask from the not interpolated data, then interpolate with scipy.interpolate.griddata() and after that somehow display the interpolated data with a mask.
Sadly, I can not think of a way to unitise my mask only to be false outside of the chamber. Is there a smart way to do this? Some ideas:

1. convolve the mask with a filter, as it is common practice in image processing
2. smart conditioning for the mask (i only checked where the data equals itself, which it does not if it is NaN)
3. interpolate not the whole grid but somehow find the missing points only at the inside, maybe with another interpolation tool

the mask:

[image: the mask]

the not interpolated data (note the inconsistent boundaries):

[image: the not interpolated data (note the inconsistent boundaries)]

the interpolated data

[image: the interpolated data]

Comment: morphology operations. dilate/erode given a mask of "valid" pixels. that'll fill the chamber for which you have samples, but leave alone any big holes as well as the outside of the chamber.

Comment: if you want people to use your pictures for demonstration, you should provide data rather than screenshots of plots. plots consist of stuff that can't just be taken to be data.

Comment: Drawing a convex hull around the shape should suffice